# Excel VBA code to select all cells with data sometimes working

Tags: vba, excel

I once built a VBA button to automatically lock all cells with data in them. And it was working perfectly. Now I wanted to copy that button to another worksheet. So I created another button, copy and pasted the whole VBA over, then edited the worksheet names and range. And, it's only working like 5% of the time, the rest of the time, I'm getting an "Run-Time error '1004': No cells were found." I've tried a few fixed, changing Sheets to Worksheets, or adding a ", 23" to the specialcells argument. However, nothing is working right now. When I try stepping in, it sometimes say both rng and lckrng as empty, and sometimes only show lockrng as empty and not show rng at all. Problem is this used to be a working code, and now, it still works around 5% of time. Any idea why? Thank you very much!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lockrng As Range

Sheets("Uploading Checklist (M)").Unprotect Password:="signature"
Set rng = Range("A1:M14")

'Selecting hardcoded data and formulas
  Set lockrng = Union(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))

lockrng.Locked = True
Sheets("Uploading Checklist (M)").Protect Password:="signature"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd like to test this out. Before I get started, I'm guessing you've ruled out stuff like formatting inconsistencies (although if you leave the second argument in SpecialCells blank it should pick all cells irrespective of formatting) and anything about the ranges being dis-contiguous?

Comment: And have you checked that you actually have both constants and formulas within that range (i.e. it isn't all constants or all formulas)?

Comment: Also as another thought: I don't know if you'd get an error if you had more than 30 discontinuous regions as arguments in Union: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-union-method-excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-union-method-excel)

Comment: P.S. I would certainly be changing `Range("A1:M14")` to be `Sheets("Uploading Checklist (M)").Range("A1:M14")` to avoid one potential source of problems.

Comment: Is the button in the sheet "`Uploading Checklist (M)`"?

Comment: @neophlegm he is giving only two arguments to the function no?

Comment: @neophlegm The 30 in that documentation would refer to the number of parameters, not what shape each of the parameters is (i.e. not how many Areas were in each parameter).  (Note: I just tested and could create a `Union` of 600 discrete, discontinuous, cells, just adding one at a time to the previous union within a loop.  I stopped at 600 - that wasn't a limit.)

Comment: If the button is in someother sheet other than `"Uploading Checklist (M)"` then @YouE3K 's comment about using `Sheets("Uploading Checklist (M)").Range("A1:M14")` should resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi all. Thank you so much for the comments and suggestions. I love this site, and I love you guys. haha.

And indeed, I have tested/double checked a lot of the things you guys have pointed out.

It's actually @YowE3K that pointed out what I believe is the problem. My range is usually mostly constants, and rarely have formulas, and now I tested that every time I added a formula, it works now. (the original of this had a range where both constantly exist.) So thanks. If you wanna post that as an official answer, I could have it as officially accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Union` you are attempting will not work if either of the parameters is `Nothing` (i.e. you either have no constants in the range, or you have no formulas in the range).

Prior to doing the `Union`, you should check the parameters aren't `Nothing` but, once you start changing your code to do that, it would be just as simple to do the locking in two parts - so I recommend you rewrite the code as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Sheets("Uploading Checklist (M)")
        .Unprotect Password:="signature"
        With .Range("A1:M14")
            'Lock any constants
            If Not .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) Is Nothing Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = True
            End If
            'Lock any formulas
            If Not .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) Is Nothing Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
            End If
        End With
        .Protect Password:="signature"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is too simplistic, but it seems to do what you want. The animated .gif shows it working to "lock all cells with data in them". (I made the second button just for convenience).  If nothing else it might be good to start from something like this that works and modify to suit your needs.

[image]

```
Dim cell As Range, sh As Worksheet

Sub Button4_Click()
Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
sh.Unprotect Password:="s"
For Each cell In sh.UsedRange
  If cell <> "" Then cell.Locked = True Else cell.Locked = False
Next
sh.Protect Password:="s"
End Sub

Sub Button5_Click()
Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
sh.Unprotect Password:="s"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Based on the comments, I have had it fixed. This code is simple and workable, so thanks. Just wondering, would it be slow if there's a large amount of data? I know in this example, the range is tiny; but from the original one I created which works, my range is something like A1:CZ300+ thingy. Would it lag (or work faster/slower) than what I originally did? Thanks.