# How to leave an edited-empty cell unlocked when sheet protection is initiated after an event

Tags: vba, excel, locking

I would like to lock cells in a worksheet when data is entered. Also, the administrator would have access to unprotect the worksheet when changes have to be made. But with this code I have the following issues:

- When data is entered and then the sheet it unprotected for deleting the data, the code then is unable to allow rentry of data into the same cells from where data was deleted, is there a good method to enable this?
- I have tried a few options that relate to Target.Cells, ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSHeet.OnEntry and Application.OnKey but nothing seems to override the delete/baackspace event.

Any help would be appreciated. This is the current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ToLock As String
Dim R As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ToLock = MsgBox("This input will now be locked.", vbOKCancel, "Confirm Change")

    ''If locking is accepted
    If ToLock <> vbOK Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents 
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    End If

''Once entry entered, sheet will be locked with this password
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "quality"
'            For Each R In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            For Each R In Target.Cells
            If R.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Locked = True
            End If
            Next R
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="quality", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider the simple code in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066696/excel-vba-code-to-select-all-cells-with-data-sometimes-working/46067408#46067408

Comment: You didn't enable ScreenUpdating if clicking Cancel. Was cells unlocked when the administrator unprotect the worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rnCell As Range, rnEmpty As Range
 On Error Resume Next

 Set rnEmpty = emptyCells(Target)
 If Not (rnEmpty Is Nothing) Then
    If rnEmpty.Address = Target.Address Then Exit Sub
 End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False

 On Error GoTo ChangeEnd
 If MsgBox("This input will now be locked.", vbOKCancel, "Confirm Change") = vbCancel Then
   Target.ClearContents
   GoTo ChangeEnd
 End If

 ActiveSheet.Unprotect "quality"
 Target.Locked = True
 Set rnEmpty = emptyCells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
 If Not (rnEmpty Is Nothing) Then rnEmpty.Locked = False

ChangeEnd:
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="quality", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function emptyCells(rnIn As Range) As Range
 On Error Resume Next
 If rnIn.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If (rnIn.Value = vbNullString) And (rnIn.Formula = vbNullString) Then
        Set emptyCells = rnIn
    End If
 Else
    Set emptyCells = rnIn.SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks)
 End If
End Function
```

Some changes were introduced for readability, some others to fit functionality you seek for, others to avoid looping. Hope that helps... any questions, please comment and will add explanation.

It should work when you paste ranges (empty cells will still be editable)

Comment: thanks for the response. The code works very well, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I do have one question, what is the reason behind this if condition? - If rnIn.Cells.Count = 1

Comment: You are welcome. The `SpecialCells` does not work properly if the number of cells in a  `Range` is not grater than `1`... something the guys of `MS` missed I guess... and then just left it like that for backwards compatibility, I presume.  If it solved your case, feel free to mark the answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: I also suggest to change the title of the question to something closer to specifics of your need (so others with similar issue can find it). Something like _leave unlocked empty cells after change event in a worksheet_ some kinda. If you find any case where the macro crashes I have seen two new lines that could make it more robust. Have not tested the case, but I think  that the line after `.UsedRange` could fail when you leave empty an edited cell of a new /empty spreadsheet (so: empty spreadsheet, edit empty cell, write something, remove content, intro)